# Mail utility in Windows Server (Same functionality like Linuz's Mail)

Tags: windows-server-2008, sendmail, email, linux

I am setting up Windows server. I would like to know is there any utility (or command or program) to send mail like the one we have in Linux to send mail (mail program in Linux).

Post an example to send mail through command prompt on Windows Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using [Blat](http://www.blat.net/) for several years. It's not syntax compatible to Linux mail, but it can mostly do the same. You do get good documentation and many samples.

Comment: Same here.  Blat has worked for years for me.

Answer (score 0):

I previously used mutt for this - but you may have to do some digging to find the native win32 port for the program.